# Did the information of the quest of Erebor leak out?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, an-unexpected-journey

The group was ambushed and chased by orcs. However, Thorin replies to Gandalf that he kept the journey secret, "tells no one".  Gandalf himself should be a good secret keeper. These make the actions of the orcs a mystery. Did they encounter the orcs coincidently?

Comment: Which part of the story is this asking about?  Were they actually somewhere where Orcs would not already be in the area?

Comment: When Gandalf and Dwarves met Radagast then they were suddently attacked by Orcs.  Gandalf looked very suprised and questioned Thorin. @suchiuomizu

Comment: Is it a surprise that people after going to confront the 6 dwarf lords information would've gotten out?

Comment: If you're asking about film then it should be tagged and highlighted.

Comment: @Mithoron I have edited the tags for precisely this reason: Harry is *clearly* asking about the Jackson film, since Radagast does not make any kind of appearance in *The Hobbit*.

Comment: Neither does Azog, since he's been dead for 142 years...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Probable, but the question is how?

It's a difficult question to answer as little detail is given in the film, however Gandalf describes the Dwarves as being hunted. We later find out that Azog is behind the orc pack and is trying to exact his vendetta on the Dwarves as outlined shortly after the Company escape from the Orc Hunting pack.

> Orc: The Dwarves, Master... we lost them. Abushed by elvish filth, we were -
> Azog: I don't want excuses. I want the head of the Dwarf King.
> <sub>The Hobbit: An Unexpected Journey</sub>

Azog is determined to have Thorin's head, and from the film it is clear that he has been looking for him. How he found his location is unclear, however Thorin did tell the six other Dwarven Kings of his plan. It is very possible through word of mouth the story got out, especially as the Dwarves traded regularly with Men.

Comment: Wouldn't it suffice to say that the orcs did not necessarily care for the quest/plan, but simply constantly kept an eye on the location of Thorin and so took their chance as soon as he entered the wilderness in a small group then? Why not classical scouting?

Comment: @PhilipKlöcking Yes it would, however hearing about the Quest of Erebor was most likely the only way Azog would've known of Thorin's whereabouts. Middle-earth is big and if he was just randomly roaming around he could've been far out of reach. The Quest however outlines a very distinctive plans depending on where the information came from. He would've been in the Blue Mountains, then Bree and heading East over/under the Misty Mountains, through Mirkwood towards Erebor. This narrows down the search area greatly.